# nginx on docker doesn't work with location URL

Tags: nginx, docker, nginx-location

I am running nginx in docker to act as a reverse proxy for multiple applications. for e.g.,

```
http://localhost/eureka/ will show http://registry:8761
http://localhost/zipkin/ will show http://zipkin:9411
```

I started with following nginx conf,

```
http {
  server {

      location /eureka/ {
          proxy_pass http://registry:9761;
      }
  }
}
```

The above configuration is not working and nginx throwing error as,

```
proxy       | 172.20.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2017:10:46:28 +0000] "GET /eureka/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36"
```

But the below configuration works for http://localhost/ showing eureka page.

```
http {
  server {

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://registry:9761;
      }
  }
}
```

What I am missing? As per [nginx proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) it should work, but its not.

Comment: The two locations are different, one passes the URI `/eureka/` to `registry:9761` and the other passes `/`. Do you need to change the URI before it is passed upstream?

Comment: I want to hide multiple applications behind nginx. if something is passed after URI, it has to be passed e.g. /eureka/abc has to be passed to http://registry:9761/abc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `proxy_pass` directive can optionally modify the URI before it is passed upstream. To remove the `/eureka/` prefix simply append the URI `/` to the `proxy_pass` statement.

For example:

```
location /eureka/ {
    proxy_pass http://registry:9761/;
}
```

The URI `/eureka/foo` will be mapped to `http://registry:9761/foo`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

Of course, this is only half of the problem. In many cases, the upstream application must access its resources using the correct prefix or a path-relative URI. Many applications cannot be forced into a subdirectory.